# What are some of the best practices to do rolling restarts for Django servers to ensure minimum problems?

Tags: python, django

When doing rolling restarts, some servers are still running the old code while some are being restarted with the new code. If you have a large number of machines/processes, there might be significant delay between the first server and the last server.

This can be a problem when there are changes to the database schema, such as columns get renamed, tables removed and etc. And this would mean that the old code (e.g using previous column names, or old tables) is still being used before the rolling restart is done.

I wonder if Django provides any guarantees or conventions to make this work well. From my own observation, when adding new models (tables) and new fields (columns) in Django this doesn't seem to cause issues with old code, because the old code doesn't even know it exists and doesn't care.

Are there any best practices or conventions in Django that one should follow to ensure minimum problems when doing a rolling restart?

Comment: Django itself does not have any specific stuff for this. If you have few servers, then you probably have a high-skilled pro to keep them running :)

Comment: uWSGI has "graceful reloads", each worker process finishes it's current request and then is replaced by a new worker process. But that's rather python-specific than django-specific...

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to serverfault?

Comment: The solution I am looking for should be focused in the Django layer. I have updated the description to elaborate more on what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinite ways to deploy a Django application - each web platform stack may have a distinct set of "best practices". That said, the [12 factors](http://www.12factor.net/) are good design principles for modern web applications.

So far, I have deployed Django using:

- linux + apache + mod_wsgi
- linux + nginx + uwsgi

I prefer to configure the server to reload the application when I touch some file (usually a blank file named "reload.me").

In my experience it is a non-issue, that is why you may not find much information about it.